# API XML Product FEED

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Quiero desarrollar un product feed con mis proveedores. Éste es el XML que me entrega el API con los productos disponibles o agotados de este distribuidor para obtener información general del producto pero principalmente stock, sku, precio...

```
<Item>
  <PartID>203237</PartID>
  <Sku>STCK-11-R8</Sku>
  <Desc>Nite Ize Steelie Car Mount Kit</Desc>
  <DescExt>
    long description... blah blah
  </DescExt>
  <CategoryID>575</CategoryID>
  <CategoryName>NITE IZE STEELIE</CategoryName>
  <PhoneMake>UNIVERSAL</PhoneMake>
  <PhoneModel>UNIVERSAL</PhoneModel>
  <Status>1</Status>
  <Cost>17.50</Cost>
  <ImageUrl>
    http://www.myvoicecomm.com/core_files/uploads/STCK-11-R8.jpg
  </ImageUrl>
  <ImageFile>STCK-11-R8.jpg</ImageFile>
  <OnHand>125</OnHand>
  <Upc>094664027312</Upc>
  <Ean/>
  <Manufacturer/>
  <Mpn>STCK-11-R8</Mpn>
  <Msrp>34.99</Msrp>
  <OptionalImages>STCK-11-R8.jpg,STCK-11-R82.jpg,STCK-11-R83.jpg</OptionalImages>
  <EtaDate/>
  <ReplacementSku/>
  <PreviousSku/>
  <FirstReceived>04/18/2013</FirstReceived>
</Item>
```

Me gustaría poder parsear el XML en un hash o arreglo para poder manipularlo y salvarlo en la base de datos. La idea es sincronizar la cantidad de veces al día que se defina eventualmente.

Son alrededor de 1000 registros, así que van entrando y saliendo dependiendo del stock o que se descontinúan. Eso simplemente se sabe si tienen stock o si está en ceros.

Comment: Hecho, quedo atento a cualquier comentario! Mil gracias!

Comment: Cuanto tu aplicación de rails hace el request a tu api como se le manda de la manera que describes arriba ?

Comment: require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.myvoicecomm.com/portal/api/itemget_form.php?api=InventoryRequest&AccountNumber=13358&AccountPassword=485zmlan01&CategoryID=&Status=1&Format=XML"))

p doc

Answer (score 0):

Pudieras parsear el XML en un hash con tu respuesta con

```
hash = Hash.from_xml(respuesta)
```

Si tu respuesta contiene espacios o saltos de linea deberás reemplazarlos antes.

```
hash = Hash.from_xml(respuesta.gsub("\n", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría de esta forma:

```
Hash.from_xml(response)
```

Este te devolverá un hash; por ejemplo, este sería el resultado del XML que proporcionas:

```
{"Item"=>
  {"PartID"=>"203237",
   "Sku"=>"STCK-11-R8",
   "Desc"=>"Nite Ize Steelie Car Mount Kit",
   "DescExt"=>"\n    long description... blah blah\n  ",
   "CategoryID"=>"575",
   "CategoryName"=>"NITE IZE STEELIE",
   "PhoneMake"=>"UNIVERSAL",
   "PhoneModel"=>"UNIVERSAL",
   "Status"=>"1",
   "Cost"=>"17.50",
   "ImageUrl"=>
    "\n    http://www.myvoicecomm.com/core_files/uploads/STCK-11-R8.jpg\n  ",
   "ImageFile"=>"STCK-11-R8.jpg",
   "OnHand"=>"125",
   "Upc"=>"094664027312",
   "Ean"=>nil,
   "Manufacturer"=>nil,
   "Mpn"=>"STCK-11-R8",
   "Msrp"=>"34.99",
   "OptionalImages"=>"STCK-11-R8.jpg,STCK-11-R82.jpg,STCK-11-R83.jpg",
   "EtaDate"=>nil,
   "ReplacementSku"=>nil,
   "PreviousSku"=>nil,
   "FirstReceived"=>"04/18/2013"}
}
```